# possible spotify portrait metadata caching bug

Tags: spotify

#### Code to replicate

In my app I have the following code.

```
var seed = "spotify:artist:3UbyYnvNIT5DFXU4WgiGpP";
  sp.core.getMetadata(seed, {
    onSuccess: function (metadata) {
      console.log(metadata);       
    },
    onFailure: function () {}
  });
```

#### Steps to view the behaviour

1. If spotify is already open close it and then reopen it, after opening spotify run the app and view the console Which displays as

```
Object
    name: "Whitesnake"
    portrait: ""
    type: "artist"
    uri: "spotify:artist:3UbyYnvNIT5DFXU4WgiGpP"
  __proto__: Object
```

1. Then click on the radio app and create a station based on the the band Whitesnake.
2. Rerun the original app and view the console output which will display.

```
Object
    name: "Whitesnake"
    portrait: "spotify:image:3c4aa30d845dd456d750cf16bef8e2cadb2af342"
    type: "artist"
    uri: "spotify:artist:3UbyYnvNIT5DFXU4WgiGpP"
  __proto__: Object
```

1. Quit spotify and rerun the original application and view the console which will display

```
Object
    name: "Whitesnake"
    portrait: ""
    type: "artist"
    uri: "spotify:artist:3UbyYnvNIT5DFXU4WgiGpP"
  __proto__: Object
```

#### Question

Why is the radio app able to access a portrait uri that is then accessible from my app after using the radio app? Is there some sort of initialization, that needs to be done first or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some information on an artist (and album, etc) isn't available until you do a "browse" on that URI - until then, Spotify only downloads basic information on an item to keep performance up.

What you're seeing is the Radio doing a browse, which causes the Spotify client to fill in the missing information.

An update to Spotify is coming soon that will improve this behaviour.

Comment: iKenndac, will this 'browse' functionality be extended to playlists? i'm having an issue where playlists won't return subscriber data unless I manually view the playlist

Comment: iKenndac. Does that mean, that sp_artist_portrait will not return an image until the browse for that artist has has been loaded. It seems a little weird to have a function like that, if it has no purpose, when the sp_artist_browse has it's own functions for returning portraits. I see in cocoalibspotify, that you haven't implemented it there either, so does that mean that it simply does not work?

Comment: Oh sorry. This question is not about libspotify. Forgive me for asking out of context.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you've noticed that after you get the result with a portrait URI from the radio, you get that object data populated when using it in your app?

On another note; you should be using the Artist class instead of sp.core.

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');
models.Artist.fromURI("spotify:artist:3UbyYnvNIT5DFXU4WgiGpP", function(album) {
    console.log(album);
});
```

This should give you the correct output with a portrait uri string.

```
Artist
    data: Object
    name: "Whitesnake"
    portrait: "spotify:image:3c4aa30d845dd456d750cf16bef8e2cadb2af342"
    type: "artist"
    uri: "spotify:artist:3UbyYnvNIT5DFXU4WgiGpP"
```

Comment: Your understanding is correct. When I quit spotify, reopen it and only run your code snippet I get the same behavior I described above.

Answer (score 1):

As iKenndac mentioned, try doing a 'browse':

```
var seed = "spotify:artist:3UbyYnvNIT5DFXU4WgiGpP";
sp.core.browseUri(seed, {  
    onSuccess: function (metadata) {
        console.log(metadata);       
    },
    onFailure: function () {}
});
```

Examples here: https://github.com/ptrwtts/kitchensink