# Get the required image from Spotify End Point

Tags: java, android, json, spotify

I'm trying to return the **id**, the **name** and the images:**url**  using this Spotify End point:

https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=artist&q=coldplay

Although it seem to return the **name** and *id** the image i.e images:**url** is null on some occasions.
How do I return all my image?

Note: See Cold & Lele as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's very rare, all artists do not have images on Spotify, and this is the case for [Coldplay & Lele](https://open.spotify.com/artist/14cDx3yNMNO94Ghqo3kVoF). The reason that this artist entry in particular doesn't have an image is probably because it's an error in Spotify's metadata since this artist doesn't have any albums related to it. Metadata issues like this one are cleaned up by a team at Spotify, and I believe the best way for users to help out with feedback is through this [funnel at Spotify's support site](https://support.spotify.com/se/contact-spotify-support/). (Technical Issues > I want to report a broken song or wrong song information)

Most importantly - Do not count on the `images` array to always contain elements. If the array is empty, use a placeholder image instead.

Comment: Thank you Michael it's really good to know that. I'll be reporting these issues soon. In the meantime (instead of using a place holder image) is there a work around ?  I read somewhere that it was to possible get the artists image from there spotify page i.e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626985/null-or-undefined-artist-images-with-spotify-apps-api?rq=1

Comment: The question you've linked to is actually using a different API, called the Apps API, that's obsolete. It was used in old clients (version < 1.0.0). There's no workaround since the artist doesn't have an image at Spotify, even in Spotify's own applications. I suppose you could work around it by checking with other services' APIs though.